# Getting error with oauth

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

I'm getting this error when I'm running twitter autoreply bot (https://gist.github.com/820281)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'Invalid auth/bad request   (got a 404, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)' in /home/.../public_html    /twitterautoreply.php:82 Stack trace: #0 /home/.../public_html/twitterautoreply.php(82): OAuth->fetch('https://twitter...', Array, 'POST') #1 /home/.../public_html/twitterautoreply.php(68):TwitterAutoReply->sendReply(Object(stdClass), 'check out this ...') #2 /home/.../public_html/run.php(13): TwitterAutoReply->run() #3 {main} thrown in /home/.../public_html/twitterautoreply.php on line 82
```

I have already checked authorization keys and secret, and it's not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is related, this week Twitter API team removed "version zero" of the API.
URLs without any version get 404 errors.

Looking at the TwitterAutoReply class on github:

```
const UPDATE_URL = 'https://twitter.com/statuses/update.json';
```

Use of statuses/update on API documentation (version 1) :

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.format
```

Comment: I wrote the script mentioned in this post. Just updated it based on this advice. Thanks!

Comment: A bit off topic : migrating to API v1.1 is pretty easy, you should :)