# Twitter OAuth Fetch 404 Error

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am working with Twitter OAuth in PHP framework and having an issue with getting through Twitter OAuth process. Everything seems to go through just fine and tokens match up all the way up to the last step that fetches user information.

The code is as follows:

```
...
$oauth->setToken($oauth_token, $session->twitter_secret);
$access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken(conf::get('TWITTER_OAUTH_ACCESS_URL'));

$session->twitter_state = 2;
$session->twitter_token = $access_token_info['oauth_token'];
$session->twitter_secret = $access_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
$session->twitter_id = $access_token_info['user_id'];

$oauth->setToken($session->twitter_token, $session->twitter_secret);

if ($oauth->fetch(conf::get('TWITTER_API_URL').'/account/verify_credentials.json'))
{
    ...
}
```

Here is the exception error output:

```
500 exception 'OAuthException' with message 'Invalid auth/bad request (got a 404, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)' in /var/www/webapp/app/controllers/default/auth.controller.php:135
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/webapp/app/controllers/default/auth.controller.php(135): OAuth->fetch('https://api.twi...')
```

Now I am at a loss as to why there is a 404 error being thrown. It also does not make sense that the error happens after all authentication steps have been passed.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is described over here:
[Getting error with oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844166/getting-error-with-oauth)

Seems that Twitter API needs to have a version number now.